# Git is not tracking Hexo theme file

Tags: git, github-pages

I have set up a Hexo blog and it is working good.
I am trying to make a backup for my local file and I am doing this by upload the file to GitHub.(Not hosting the page, as I have done that)
However, there is an issue when I stage the file.

[image]

As far as I know, the `themes/icarus` stores the theme file I am using for my blog AND this file is not tracking file.  I have checked my `.gitignore` file, it looks like this:

[image]

How to fix this issue, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified content, untracked content means that themes/icarus folder is a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.

Check your `.gitmodules` file, you should see it there.

If you do any modification in a submodule, you must add, commit and piush in that submodule first (assuming you can push to its remote repository), before adding/committing and pushing in the main project.

Comment: I just checked the .gitmodules, I opened it by running '.gitmodules', it is empty in the file. Should I add themes/icarus in the file?

Comment: @Nan No: it can means the folder is a nested Git repo: do you see a `.git/` in themes/icarus?

Comment: No. As far as I just have a look, I see nothing in the folder.

Comment: I just run nano .git in the folder and the file is empty

Comment: @Nan That would be an hidden folder. If not, search for an icarus subfolder in your main .git project folder.

Comment: Issue is resolve.  I use command line to access the icarus folder.  I commit the changes in the folder.  Then I jump out the folder and run git add -A, then commit.  It works this way.

Comment: @Nan Well done. Do check you can clone again your repo and find back the right content for that subfolder, once cloned again.

Comment: Will do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If a file is not staged in Git, it means you have not added it to be included by the next commit. Try `git add themes/icarus` or `git add -A`, before you commit. This should stage the file.

Comment: I have tried it, and it is saying file not staged to commit

Comment: Dev_Blog nan$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

 modified:   themes/icarus (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
nans-mbp:Dev_Blog nan$

Comment: And it doesn't show you an error, when you try `git add themes/icarus`?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with you and I solved this by running following commands.

1. Make sure you already removed .git/ for every submodule directories.

```sh
git rm -rf .git
```

2. Remove cached files in root directory of git repo

```sh
git rm -r --cached .
```

3. Add and commit all files again

```sh
git commit -am 'commit message'
```